# Why is my GAN only producing grey images and not making any progress?

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to make a GAN but whenever I try to train it, the output is just gray images and doesn't make any progress. My code is below, I'd appreciate any help. I think it might have something to do with the way I am saving the images, but even if I change that, the images are colored but the generator is making no progress and I don't know why.

```
def save_images(cnt, noise, generator):
  image_array = np.full((PREVIEW_MARGIN + (PREVIEW_ROWS * (IMAGE_SIZE + PREVIEW_MARGIN)), PREVIEW_MARGIN + (PREVIEW_COLS * (IMAGE_SIZE + PREVIEW_MARGIN)), 3), 255, dtype=np.uint8)
  generated_images = generator.predict(noise)
  generated_images = 0.5 * generated_images + 0.5
  image_count = 0
  for row in range(PREVIEW_ROWS):
    for col in range(PREVIEW_COLS):
      r = row * (IMAGE_SIZE + PREVIEW_MARGIN) + PREVIEW_MARGIN
      c = col * (IMAGE_SIZE + PREVIEW_MARGIN) + PREVIEW_MARGIN
      image_array[r:r + IMAGE_SIZE, c:c + IMAGE_SIZE] = generated_images[image_count] * 255
      image_count += 1
  output_path = 'output'
  if not os.path.exists(output_path):
    os.makedirs(output_path)
  filename = os.path.join(output_path, f"trained-{cnt}.png")
  im = Image.fromarray(image_array)
  im.save(filename)

def get_optimizer():
    return Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)

def get_generator():
  gen_input = Input(shape=random_dim)
  generator = Sequential()
  
  generator.add(Dense(128 * 16 * 16, input_dim=random_dim))
  generator.add(LeakyReLU())
  generator.add(Reshape((16, 16, 128)))

  generator.add(Conv2D(256, 5, padding='same'))
  generator.add(LeakyReLU())

  generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(256, 4, strides=2, padding='same'))
  generator.add(LeakyReLU())

  generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(256, 4, strides=2, padding='same'))
  generator.add(LeakyReLU())

  generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(256, 4, strides=2, padding='same'))
  generator.add(LeakyReLU())

  generator.add(Conv2D(512, 5, padding='same'))
  generator.add(LeakyReLU())
  generator.add(Conv2D(512, 5, padding='same'))
  generator.add(LeakyReLU())

  generator.add(Conv2D(3, 7, activation='tanh', padding='same'))

  input = Input(shape=(random_dim,))
  generated_image = generator(input)

  return Model(input, generated_image)

def get_discriminator():
  disc_input = Input(shape=(128, 128, 3))
  discriminator = Sequential()
  
  discriminator.add(Conv2D(32, 3, input_shape=(128, 128, 3)))
  discriminator.add(LeakyReLU())

  discriminator.add(Conv2D(64, 4, strides=2))
  discriminator.add(LeakyReLU())

  discriminator.add(Conv2D(128, 4, strides=2))
  discriminator.add(LeakyReLU())

  discriminator.add(Conv2D(256, 4, strides=2))
  discriminator.add(LeakyReLU())

  discriminator.add(Conv2D(512, 4, strides=2))
  discriminator.add(LeakyReLU())

  discriminator.add(Flatten())
  discriminator.add(Dropout(0.4))

  discriminator.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
  discriminator = Model(disc_input, discriminator(disc_input))

  optimizer = RMSprop(
      lr = .0001,
      clipvalue = 1.0,
      decay = 1e-8
  )

  discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)

  return discriminator

def get_gan_network(discriminator, random_dim, generator, optimizer):
  # We initially set trainable to False since we only want to train either the
  # generator or discriminator at a time
  discriminator.trainable = False
  # gan input (noise) will be 100-dimensional vectors
  gan_input = Input(shape=(random_dim,))
  # the output of the generator (an image)
  x = generator(gan_input)
  # get the output of the discriminator (probability if the image is real or not)
  gan_output = discriminator(x)
  gan = Model(inputs=gan_input, outputs=gan_output)
  gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
  return gan

X_train = training_data
fixed_noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (PREVIEW_ROWS * PREVIEW_COLS, 100))
def train(epochs=1, batchSize=128):
  batchCount = X_train.shape[0] / batchSize
  print(X_train.shape[0])
  print('Epochs:', epochs)
  print('Batch size:', batchSize)
  print('Batches per epoch:', batchCount)

  adam = get_optimizer()
  generator = get_generator()
  discriminator = get_discriminator()
  gan = get_gan_network(discriminator, random_dim, generator, adam)

  for step in tdqm(range(1000)):
    # Get a random set of input noise and images
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=[batchSize, random_dim])
    imageBatch = X_train[np.random.randint(0, X_train.shape[0], size=batchSize)]

    # Generate fake  images
    generatedImages = generator.predict(noise)
  
    # Labels for generated and real data
    yDis = np.zeros(2*batchSize)
    # One-sided label smoothing
    yDis[:batchSize] = 0.9

    # Train generator
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=[batchSize, random_dim])
    yGen = np.ones(batchSize)
    discriminator.trainable = False

    if step == 1 or step % 20 == 0:
      save_images(step, fixed_noise, generator)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    train(1000, 128)
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot see in your code where you are calculating the generator & discriminator loss according to the GAN training method and backpropagating it through the networks. Essentially from your code I cannot observe any training happening. Please refer to the following example - https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan

Comment: GANs are notoriously hard to get working. You're likely experiencing mode collapse

Comment: With regards to my first comment. I do not see a tf.train method (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Yes, you are correct that would make sense.